# Reproduce forest plot in R

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I'm trying to create a forest plot similar to this one for my article -
[Forest plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMN5N.png)

I'm having trouble reproducing it, first creating the horizontal grey lines and secondly creating this many columns.
Anyone has an idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide any data / code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.